# Interpretar tags de arquivo XML com PHP

Tags: php, xml

Estou com dificuldades para interpretar um arquivo XML com PHP. A dificuldade que tenho é não conseguir pegar os valores de acordo com sua tag. O laço do xml traz essa dificuldade para mim. Vejam um resumo dele:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <id_couponoffer>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[192756]]>
        </value>
    </id_couponoffer>
    <title>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[Fast Runner]]>
        </value>
    </title>
    <startdate>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[2016-11-30]]>
        </value>
    </startdate>
    <enddate>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[2017-03-31]]>
        </value>
    </enddate>
    <url>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[http://v2.afilio.com.br/tracker.php?banid=4295676&campid=26275;2043&siteid=32790]]>
        </value>
    </url>
    <discount>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </value>
    </discount>
    <progid>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[2043]]>
        </value>
    </progid>
    <rule>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[Oferta]]>
        </value>
    </rule><code><value><![CDATA[sem]]></value></code>
    <description>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[LanÃ§amento: TÃŠNIS HOKA M BONDI 4 Por R$ 899,90]]>
        </value>
    </description>
    <type>
        <value>
            <![CDATA[n]]>
        </value>
    </type>
</root>
```

Não estou conseguindo usar foreach para pegar somente alguns valores.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://v2.afilio.com.br/api/feedproducts.php?token=53e355fe881a30.10592737&mode=dl&siteid=32790&affid=26275&format=XML');

foreach ($xml as $result) {

    echo $result->value;
    echo '</br>';
}
```

Quando uso $result->value, ela puxa todos os valores do xml. O que quero é pegar apenas alguns e organizá-los.

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar Xpath para isso :

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xml = "data_export.xml";
$dom->load($xml); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('/root/id_couponoffer');
for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
    $id_couponoffer = $xpath->query('/root/id_couponoffer');
    echo "id_couponoffer    :".$id_couponoffer->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";

    $title = $xpath->query('/root/title');
    echo "title :".$title->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";

    $startdate = $xpath->query('/root/startdate');
    echo "startdate :".$startdate->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";
}
echo "E assim por diante....";
?>
```

Dê uma olhada nessa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169892/domxpath-query-com-multiplas-classes)(note que ela usa html e não xml) e veja outras formas de implementar.

Comment: Então, o código com o xml eu só publiquei pra mostrar as tags, mas eu não consigo visualizá-lo dessa forma no PHP. No php, eu carrego o arquivo XML, como pode ser visto antes do foreach. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Basta você colocar o arquivo aqui : `$dom->loadXML("arquivo.xml");`, lembre-se caso alguma resposta esteja correta considere validá-la, clicando no icon abaixo das setas de avaliação.

Comment: Fiz uma edição veja, se agora vai...

Comment: Eu fiz isso que você falou, aí na sequência eu usei print_r($xpath) e mostrou o seguinte: DOMXPath Object ( [document] => (object value omitted) )

Comment: veja a edição que fiz, repare ali que troquei : `$dom->loadXML($xml);` por `$dom->load($xml);`.

Comment: Sim, após sua edição deu certo, mostrou os resultados. No caso, os foreach fazem referência a um elemento específico, gerando todos os id_couponoffer primeiro, depois a sequência de title e assim sucessivamente. Eu quero organizar cada id_couponoffer com sua respectiva title, é possível com Xpath?

Comment: Dá sim vou editar... Aí se usa o `for`...Pronto veja agora

Comment: Oh dei mais uma editada, tô fazendo outra coisa aqui, tô meio desatento... Agora tá redondim...

Comment: MagicHat, muitíssimo obrigado. Ao mesmo tempo em que você ia respondendo eu tentava aqui achar uma luz, inclusive tentando, sem sucesso, usar o for. Após essa sua última edição ficou perfeito. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Valeu mesmo!!!!!!