# Pegar string dentro de tag <a> sem atributos

Tags: php, web-crawler

Eu estou utilizando dom no PHP para pegar o link de uma tag , onde através do "getAttribute" eu consigo pegar tal link pelo atributo href.

Script do crawler:

```
<?php
//carregamento da url
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.linkdosite.com.br");

//pega somente os links
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//array que armazena o valor do crawler
$getLink = array();

$nlinks = 0;

foreach ($links as $pegalink) {

    //aqui pega cada link 
    $link = $pegalink->getAttribute('href');

    $termo = 'detalhe';//Termo para diferenciar dos demias links e pegar apenas os que contenham o termo

    $pattern = '/' . $termo . '/';//Padrão a ser encontrado na string $link

    if (preg_match($pattern, $link)) {
        $getLink[$nlinks] = $link;//Atribui o link ao array $getLink 

        echo $getLink[$nlinks]."<br>";//Imprime o link na tela

        $nlinks++;
    } 

}
```

---

Agora, também preciso pegar a string que está dentro da tag 'a', não encontrei nenhum exemplo para me ajudar a resolver isso.

Bloco que eu pego via crawler:

```
<a href="link">
  <font style="font-size: 14px;" color="black" face="arial"><b>String que eu quero pegar</b></font>
</a>
```

---

Comment: Qual classe você está usando ? mas provavellmente é algo como no jQuery ('a font b')->html();

Comment: não tem classe, isso é um crawler de outro site...precisa acontecer tudo no server side

Comment: Sim sim, mas você não está usando uma classe PHP pra acessar o DOM ? por exemplo eu uso essa classe: https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery

Comment: Não...estou usando o próprio dom do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para você recuperar o valor dos atributos / recuperar a string dentro de uma tag, faça o seguinte:

**Exemplo:**

```
//carregamento da url
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://google.com.br");

//pega somente os links
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$nlinks = 0;
foreach($links as $link) {
    // Recupera o texto dentro da tag
    echo $link->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    // Recupera o valor de um atributo
    echo $links->item($nlinks)->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
    $nlinks++;
}
```

Na documentação do PHP, tem uma nota de contribuição com o [exemplo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#89313).

Comment: Pronto! Muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php):

```
<?php
$text = '<a href="link">
  <font style="font-size: 14px;" color="black" face="arial"><b>String que eu quero pegar</b></font>
</a>
';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Xf6l3l)

Existem muitas formas de se atingir o resultado que você está buscando, com DOMXpath(como dito pelo @Lacobus  e mencionado no link que ti enviei), dá pra fazer com DOM... Mas esse tipo de coisa(scraping) é bem específico porque depende da estrutura da página alvo...

A maneira mais universal seria a seguinte:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229996/pegar-string-dentro-de-tag-a-sem-atributos");
$link = preg_match_all("/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a\>/",$str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Se isso não servir coloca o link do site pra eu ver a estrutura...

Comment: Então, mas no meu caso por se tratar de um crawler de outro site, as tags estão renderizadas em HTML mesmo, eu teria que dar um jeito de pegar essas tags específicas, converter em string para usar o strip_tags...é possível fazer isso através do DOM?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169892/domxpath-query-com-multiplas-classes

Comment: Acontece que no meu caso não existe classe ou atributo nas tags que eu preciso.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Sim estou utilizando: $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'). Agora preciso transformar esse bloco de tags que eu pego em uma string para eu poder usar o strip_tags conforme o seu exemplo. Isso que eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Vou precisar dar uma saída, mais tarde tento editar minha resposta, mas faz o seguinte edita sua questão e coloca seu código completo do crawler...

Comment: @CharlesFay editei...

Answer (score 1):

Use o método `evaluate()` da classe `DOMXPath`:

```
<?php

$html = "<a href=\"link\"><font style=\"font-size: 14px;\" color=\"black\" face=\"arial\"><b>String que eu quero pegar</b></font></a>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadXML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$str = $xp->evaluate("string(/a)");

echo $str;
```

Comment: Então, você declarou o bloco html como uma string, no meu caso eu pego o bloco html via: $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'). Com isso através dos recursos da DOM PHP eu consigo trabalhar certas coisas, ex: $pegalink->getAttribute('href') eu consigo pegar o link. Mas como esse bloco de html não é uma string, eu não consigo utilizar o seu exemplo.